# Generic Mapping in AutoMapper With Reverse Map Gives System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, .net-7.0

Using reverse map in AutoMapper is giving me following error

**"System.ArgumentException: 'Type AutoMapperWorker.Context.Tenant`1[TClientKey] is a generic type definition (Parameter 'type')'"**

***Following is my Database Class***:

```
public class Tenant<TClientKey>
where TClientKey : IEquatable<TClientKey>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public TClientKey TenantId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string? Host { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string? Folder { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public TClientKey ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client<TClientKey>? Client { get; set; }

}
```

***Following is my View Model:***

```
public class TenantVM<TClientKey>
where TClientKey : IEquatable<TClientKey>
{
    public TClientKey TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string Folder { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ClientBreifVM<TClientKey> Client { get; set; } = new ClientBreifVM<TClientKey>();

}
```

***Mapping:***

```
public class Mapping : Profile
{
    public Mapping()
    {
        CreateMap(typeof(ClientBreifVM<>), typeof(Client<>))
            .ForMember("ClientId", opt => opt.MapFrom("Id"))
            .ReverseMap();
        CreateMap(typeof(TenantVM<>), typeof(Tenant<>))
            .ReverseMap();

    }
}
```

***Dependency Injection:***

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Mapping));
```

If I don't use Reverse map and write bidirectional mapping as follow it works:

```
CreateMap(typeof(TenantVM<>), typeof(Tenant<>));
CreateMap(typeof(Tenant<>), typeof(TenantVM<>));
```

Can anyone explain why?
Here is the link to github repo [Github Repo Link](https://github.com/safi-07/automappertest.git)

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: All those `ForMember` are useless. That's a built in convention.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I have made the edits and also added the link to repository. Can you please check now?

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Install-Package : NU1102: Unable to find package AutoMapper with version (>= 12.0.1-preview.0.3)
  - Found 220 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 12.0.0 ]

Comment: I suggest you read the docs more carefully. It's there :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu okay it works with the pre release version

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that `ReverseMap` tries to reverse a `MapFrom` to `ForPath`, see https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html.

But that doesn't really work for open generic maps as there is no `string` based `ForPath`, so, inside AM, the fix is to simply skip it.

As you've noticed, in your own code, you can avoid `ReverseMap` and create the needed maps explicitly. Unless you actually rely on this reversing behaviour, this should make your maps easier to understand.